# CDK: which command should I run after changing my code?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I'm running aws serverless using aws cdk and aws-sdk.

I wrote my code and then ran the following commands:

```
cdk synth
cdk deploy
```

Now I update the code locally on my machine and want to push the changes.

- Which command/s should I run now?
- Should I run `cdk destroy` in between?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run the same commands again
cdk synth
cdk deploy

Answer (score 4):

Running `cdk deploy` will first synthesize the stacks and then deploy the changes. No need to run synth prior.
Deploying will apply the current stack and destroy any recourses that are no longer in the code, so no need to run destroy first.

Answer (score 3):

Use `cdk watch`. Cdk will observe the files you specified in your `cdk.json` file and **automatically deploy your changes**, which also makes it much faster.

Here is the `cdk watch` documentation:

- https://cdkworkshop.com/20-typescript/30-hello-cdk/300-cdk-watch.html#cdk-watch (start here)
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/increasing-development-speed-with-cdk-watch/